# Trying to connect a PostgreSQL database to Eclipse

Tags: postgresql, java

I have a Postgres (version 9.2) database running on a Centos 7 machine, and I'm trying to connect to it from Eclipse Oxygen on a Windows 10 machine using the Data Source Explorer.

When I put in all the information on the Connection Details screen in Eclipse and hit "Test Connection", I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:250)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.<init>(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:152)
... 14 more
```

I'm pretty new to Centos and Postgres, so I'm not entirely sure what all of this means. I know that the information that I put in to connect to it is correct. I'm able to ping the Centos machine from Windows and I'm able to ping the Windows machine from Centos. I am also able to connect to the Centos machine from Windows with Putty, if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This line shows the problem:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

As a rule of thumb, typically in Java stacktraces, the first "Caused by" (printed last) is what you want.

Your Win10 can't connect to the postgresql on your CentOS. PostgreSQL uses typically the TCP port 5432.

It gets a connection timeout error, which means your win10 absolutely doesn't get an answer. Nothing. If your postgresql wouldn't allow the connection, or if your postgresql wouldn't listen on your tcp port 5432, you had got "authentication error" or "connection refused" error.

But your win10 doesn't get anything, not even an error. As if your server wouldn't even exist.

You can check the availability of your postgresql with a

```
telnet your.centos.ip 5432
```

command.

The most probably cause of your problem is that the default firewall configuration of your centos simply filters out the 5432 port. Enable it.

The second most probable cause is that you simply typed in a false IP.

If you solved that problem, then

1. your telnet command won't hang up
2. your java software will connect, or at least it will have a different error (authentication error or connection refused are the most likely).

Making postgresql listening on the network requires also some different settings, beside your firewall configuration:

- You have to set up your postgresql to listen on all IP addresses, not only on localhost. This can be done with a `listen_addresses` line of your `postgresql.conf`.
- You have to set up some authentication (md5 password is the most likely) in the `pg_hba.conf`.

First connect your postgresql with some client, for example with [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) or with the command line `psql` tool (it comes also with cygwin). After it works, only then play to connect it from Java.

Comment: "PostgreSQL uses typically the TCP port 5432."  < This just solved several hours of frustration. I apparently had the wrong port after getting the same error as the OP. This got me connected to my Google Cloud DB instantly. Thank you!